# An Alternative to a Cursor For This?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find a way to accomplish this without using a cursor.

I have a set of data that totals about 13 million records. The interval between one record and the next varies, but are all between 5 and 20 minutes. 
I need to create a new table of data, but select the data so that this is at least a 30 minute gap between one record and the next.

For example, if I have this:

```
VID | Datetime
1   |  2016-01-01 00:00
1   |  2016-01-01 00:10
1   |  2016-01-01 00:12
1   |  2016-01-01 00:25
2   |  2016-01-01 00:40
4   |  2016-01-01 01:00
4   |  2016-01-01 02:13
6   |  2016-01-01 02:23
7   |  2016-01-01 02:25
8   |  2016-01-01 02:49
9   |  2016-01-01 02:59
9   |  2016-01-01 03:01
9   |  2016-01-01 03:09
9   |  2016-01-01 03:24
9   |  2016-01-01 04:05
```

The new table would look like this:

```
VID | Datetime
1   |  2016-01-01 00:00
2   |  2016-01-01 00:40
4   |  2016-01-01 02:13
8   |  2016-01-01 02:49
9   |  2016-01-01 03:24
```

I can do this with a cursor, but for millions of records that's crazy.  I've seen mentions of something called a quirky update for similar situations, but I'm not sure what that is.

Currently using SQL Server 2014.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The quirky update has a pretty specific list of requirements for it to work correctly. It is also undocumented behavior and as such it may or may not always work for you. However, Jeff Moden has a great article on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/ The downside is that I don't think that is what you want here. It seems that you want the lowest datetime value in each 30 minute window. You could probably use ROW_NUMBER with a partition here. If nobody provides an answer I will try to work something up after I get back from a meeting.

Comment: @SeanLange:  Thanks!

Comment: Times like this I really wish my work would get its shit together and get off 2008. I am feeling a Lead/Lag answer, but can't test at work.

Comment: I see speed issues on 13 million records :-) Instead of going through and finding the next record > 30 minutes would it be acceptable to get any record in each 30 minute interval?

Comment: I do hope there's an index in vid, datetime

Comment: What is going to work for you going forward in your situation?  Is this a one-time conversion or do you have a stream of data like that coming in every day and you will want to put it into the grouped by time buckets as the data comes in?  I am just pointing out that focusing on the 13 million records may mislead you to the solution you really want on an ongoing daily basis as you move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Things would be a lot easier if you had an identifier column instead of [vid].
If that was the case then you could do this:

```
with mycte (id, mydate, keepthis, offset)
as
(
    select
        id,
        mydate,
        1 keepthis,
        0 offset
    from mytable where id = 1
    union all
    select
        t.id,
        t.mydate,
        case when datediff(mi, o.mydate, t.mydate)+o.offset >= 30 then 1 else 0 end keepthis,
        case when datediff(mi, o.mydate, t.mydate)+o.offset >= 30 then 0 else datediff(mi, o.mydate, t.mydate)+o.offset end
    from mytable t join mycte o on t.id = o.id+1
)

select id,mydate from mycte where keepthis=1
```

Comment: I can use ROW_NUMBER() to add an id. The records are ordered by datetime asc.  I will try this.

Comment: Is it because of the missing vid coloumn?

Answer (score 1):

Thinking a little outside the box, if it is permissible to just get the earliest row in each 30 min interval then I have a solution that works.

Caveats:

- I assumed at this point your data might go back as far as 30 years. 13 million intervals approaches the limit of the way the tally table is configured so if you go over 16 mil you will need to make changes
- You may need to break up the CTEs as temp tables and add indexes to get decent performance on that data :-)

--

```
--setup data
declare @t table (VID int, [Datetime] datetime);
insert  @t values
        (1, '1986-01-01 00:00'),    --very early year
        (1, '2016-01-01 00:10'),
        (1, '2016-01-01 00:12'),
        (1, '2016-01-01 00:25'),
        (2, '2016-01-01 00:40'),
        (4, '2016-01-01 01:00'),
        (4, '2016-01-01 02:13'),
        (6, '2016-01-01 02:23'),
        (7, '2016-01-01 02:25'),
        (8, '2016-01-01 02:49'),
        (9, '2016-01-01 02:59'),
        (9, '2016-01-01 03:01'),
        (9, '2016-01-01 03:09'),
        (9, '2016-01-01 03:24'),
        (9, '2016-01-01 04:05');
select  * from @t order by VID, [Datetime];
--select    datediff(MI, (select min([Datetime]) from @t), (select max([Datetime]) from @t));   --15778325 records in 30 years - handled by t4 x t4 x t4 in tally generator

-- Tally generator courtesy of http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/never_say_never/2010/03/19/tally_2D00_table_2D00_cte/
-- Tally Table CTE script (SQL 2005+ only)
-- You can use this to create many different numbers of rows... for example:
-- You could use a 3 way cross join (t3 x, t3 y, t3 z) instead of just 2 way to generate a different number of rows.
-- The # of rows this would generate for each is noted in the X3 comment column below.
-- For most common usage, I find t3 or t4 to be enough, so that is what is coded here.
-- If you use t3 in ‘Tally’, you can delete t4 and t5.
; WITH
    -- Tally table Gen            Tally Rows:     X2                X3
t1 AS (SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT 1 N),    -- 4            ,    8
t2 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM t1 x, t1 y),            -- 16            ,    64
t3 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM t2 x, t2 y),            -- 256            ,    4096
t4 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM t3 x, t3 y),            -- 65536        ,    16,777,216
t5 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM t4 x, t4 y),            -- 4,294,967,296,    A lot
Tally AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) N
          FROM t4 x, t4 y, t4 z), -- Change the t3's to one of the other numbers above for more/less rows
--generate time values
Intervals as (
        select  t.N - 1 interval,
                dateadd(mi, (t.N - 1) * 30, min_date.min_date) interval_start,
                dateadd(mi, (t.N) * 30, min_date.min_date) next_interval_start
        from    (
                select  min([Datetime]) min_date
                from    @t
                ) min_date
        join    Tally t
                on  t.N <= datediff(MI, (select min([Datetime]) from @t), (select max([Datetime]) from @t)) / 30 + 1
),
--join intervals to data tables
Intervaled_data as (
        select  *, row_number() over (partition by i.interval order by t.[Datetime]) row_num
        from    @t t
        join    Intervals i
                on  t.[Datetime] >= i.interval_start and t.[Datetime] < i.next_interval_start
)
select  i.VID, i.[Datetime]
from    Intervaled_data i
where   i.row_num = 1
order   by i.VID, i.[Datetime];
```

Comment: hmmm..interesting.  Let me test this.